# how to replace string when Javascript string variable may contain forward slash?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort out how to replace a substring in a string when the substring to be found/replaced is a variable that may have one or more occurrences of a forward slash.  I suspect the issue is in escaping the incoming string properly....but I'm kind of lost on the syntax to insert the escapes correctly.

```
var incomingStr = 'some text/take / out/ and yet more.';
var removethis = '/take / out/';
newStr = incomingStr.replace(removethis," ");
newStr should be:  'some text and yet more.'
```

Comment: escape the forward slash using a backslash `\/`

Answer (score 3):

You can "quote" or "escape" it using a backslash:

```
var removethis = '/take \/ out/';
```

Or if you prefer, you can wrap it in a character class:

```
var removethis = '/take [/] out/';
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work! Here is an example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pipalia/BdvZn/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            function testStr() {
                var incomingStr = 'some text/take / out/ and yet more.';
                var removethis = '/take / out/';
                var newStr = incomingStr.replace(removethis,"");
                alert(newStr);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="testStr()">Click here</button>
    </body>
</html>​
```